How can I switch between battery tracking mode and input voltage regulation mode on the BQ24210?
I'm trying to create a circuit in which a BQ24210 automatically switches between charging a battery via battery tracking mode and charging it via input voltage regulation mode. This is done by having the VDPM pin of the BQ24210 pin left floating or connected to VSS through some resistance. I need to do this because I'm using two ideal diodes (LM66100s) to OR my power supplies, which are either 5V from USB or ~5V from a solar cell. These ideal diodes have status pins which are open drain and pulled low when the chip is disabled. My thinking was I could use the invert the status pin of the USB ORing diode and drive some MOSFET to connect the VDPM pin to ground through that resistor. Would using the ST pin from one of the ideal diodes to connect the VDPM pin to ground through a resistor or leave it floating be a viable solution? What might this look like? Thanks!
The schematic is below


Can you ask a specific question?

@VoltageSpike Edited
